# How to prevent assets being directly reachable with flutter web app?

Tags: flutter, dart, web, assets

When I build my flutter web app and host it online, if you know the url of the assets you can just enter these into the browser and load all the assets directly. Can I setup the app in a way that only the app can access them?

Found no solution so far

Comment: Are you password protecting the app?

Comment: This would not help my case: Users of this app (so they might have such PW) should still not be able to extract the resources by entering the URLs directly

Comment: Accessing assets by URL is how the web works at best you can allow access only by authorized users.